# Dynamo python Script returns null at OUT but works

Tags: python, revit-api, revit

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X2Ex.png)

Here is the code. It creates callOuts correctly but returns null values at OUT.
 the code is rough but i think is not the cause

Comment: Could you please copy-paste the relevant parts of your code? (Maybe all, it is not that long). Links may get broken over time. Thanks.

Comment: just pasted the relevant code abobe appears imports and references